# React Amchart5 DrawingControl Causing Uncaught Error: You cannot have multiple Roots on the same DOM node how to implement DrawingControl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amcharts

I am trying to add a Candlestick chart to my React project, and I am having issues with the following.

When I use:

```
am5stock.StockToolbar.new(root, {
      container: document.getElementById("chartcontrols"),
      stockChart: stockChart,
      controls: [
        am5stock.IndicatorControl.new(root, {
          stockChart: stockChart,
          legend: valueLegend
        }),       
        am5stock.ResetControl.new(root, {
          stockChart: stockChart
        }),
        am5stock.SettingsControl.new(root, {
          stockChart: stockChart
        })am5stock.DateRangeSelector.new(root, {
          stockChart: stockChart
        }),
        am5stock.PeriodSelector.new(root, {
          stockChart: stockChart
        }),
      ]
    });
```

The chart renders fine no problems, but when I add the following item to containers:

```
        am5stock.DrawingControl.new(root, {
          stockChart: stockChart
        }),
```

It produces the error React Amchart5 Uncaught Error:

```
You cannot have multiple Roots on the same DOM node.
```

I have tried creating a global array storing the roots, and then removing them when the component mounts I have also as you can see implemented a common solution posted on this site where you iterate over am5.array.each(am5.registry.rootElements, function(root) and use the dispose method. However this causes the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: el is undefined removeElement Utils.ts:46 _dispose DrawingControl.ts:1114 dispose Entity.ts:909 dispose Root.ts:1261 each Array.ts:93 dispose Root.ts:1260
```

This suggests to me the problem is with `DrawingControl` in fact when I comment out the other container items, and only include `DrawingControl`, it crashes with the same error `el` is not defined, so I suppose I am not implementing it correctly? However, when I have followed the documentation and can't see any obvious error in my implementation, but maybe I have been looking at this problem too long and was hoping someone could help me!.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as am5 from "@amcharts/amcharts5";
import * as am5xy from "@amcharts/amcharts5/xy";
import * as am5stock from "@amcharts/amcharts5/stock";
import am5themes_Animated from "@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated";

class App extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    am5.array.each(am5.registry.rootElements, function(root) {
      if (root.dom.id == "chartdiv") {
        root.dispose();
      }
    });
    var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

    root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

    root.container.children.clear();
    var stockChart = root.container.children.push(
      am5stock.StockChart.new(root, {})
    );

    root.numberFormatter.set("numberFormat", "#,###.00");

    var mainPanel = stockChart.panels.push(
      am5stock.StockPanel.new(root, {
        wheelY: "zoomX",
        panX: true,
        panY: true,
        height: am5.percent(70)
      })
    );

    var valueAxis = mainPanel.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
          pan: "zoom"
        }),
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {}),
        numberFormat: "#,###.00",
        extraTooltipPrecision: 2
      })
    );

    var dateAxis = mainPanel.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.GaplessDateAxis.new(root, {
        baseInterval: {
          timeUnit: "day",
          count: 1
        },
        groupData: true,
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
      })
    );

    var valueSeries = mainPanel.series.push(
      am5xy.CandlestickSeries.new(root, {
        name: "MSFT",
        valueXField: "Date",
        valueYField: "Close",
        highValueYField: "High",
        lowValueYField: "Low",
        openValueYField: "Open",
        calculateAggregates: true,
        xAxis: dateAxis,
        yAxis: valueAxis,
        legendValueText: "{valueY}"
      })
    );

    stockChart.set("stockSeries", valueSeries);

    var valueLegend = mainPanel.plotContainer.children.push(
      am5stock.StockLegend.new(root, {
        stockChart: stockChart
      })
    );
    valueLegend.data.setAll([valueSeries]);

    mainPanel.set(
      "cursor",
      am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {
        yAxis: valueAxis,
        xAxis: dateAxis,
        snapToSeries: [valueSeries],
        snapToSeriesBy: "y!"
      })
    );

    var scrollbar = mainPanel.set(
      "scrollbarX",
      am5xy.XYChartScrollbar.new(root, {
        orientation: "horizontal",
        height: 50
      })
    );
    stockChart.toolsContainer.children.push(scrollbar);

    var sbDateAxis = scrollbar.chart.xAxes.push(
      am5xy.GaplessDateAxis.new(root, {
        baseInterval: {
          timeUnit: "day",
          count: 1
        },
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
      })
    );

    var sbValueAxis = scrollbar.chart.yAxes.push(
      am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
      })
    );

    var sbSeries = scrollbar.chart.series.push(
      am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
        valueYField: "Close",
        valueXField: "Date",
        xAxis: sbDateAxis,
        yAxis: sbValueAxis
      })
    );

    sbSeries.fills.template.setAll({
      visible: true,
      fillOpacity: 0.3
    });

    function loadData(ticker, series) {
      am5.net
        .load(
          "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/assets/docs/stock/" +
            ticker +
            ".csv"
        )
        .then(function (result) {
          var data = am5.CSVParser.parse(result.response, {
            delimiter: ",",
            skipEmpty: true,
            useColumnNames: true
          });

          var processor = am5.DataProcessor.new(root, {
            dateFields: ["Date"],
            dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
            numericFields: [
              "Open",
              "High",
              "Low",
              "Close",
              "Adj Close",
              "Volume"
            ]
          });
          processor.processMany(data);

          am5.array.each(series, function (item) {
            item.data.setAll(data);
          });
        });
    }

    loadData("MSFT", [valueSeries, sbSeries]);

     am5stock.StockToolbar.new(root, {
  container: document.getElementById("chartcontrols"),
  stockChart: stockChart,
  controls: [
    am5stock.IndicatorControl.new(root, {
      stockChart: stockChart,
      legend: valueLegend
    }),
    am5stock.DateRangeSelector.new(root, {
      stockChart: stockChart
    }),
    am5stock.PeriodSelector.new(root, {
      stockChart: stockChart
    }),
    am5stock.DrawingControl.new(root, {
      stockChart: stockChart
    }),
    am5stock.ResetControl.new(root, {
      stockChart: stockChart
    }),
    am5stock.SettingsControl.new(root, {
      stockChart: stockChart
    })
  ]
});

    this.root = root;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.root) {
      this.root.dispose();
      this.root.container.children.clear();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return [
      <div
        id="chartcontrols"
        style={{ height: "auto", padding: "5px 45px 0 15px" }}
      ></div>,
      <div id="chartdiv" style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }}></div>
    ];
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: based on my experience, i usually create dynamic name for the root